# How the upload by region in AWS stack works?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am unable to understand regions in AWS stack. I read somewhere in aws document that uploading data(S3) for one region does not reflects automatically to other region. Do I need to upload to all available regions to reflects my uploaded file world wide?
However I used to upload to S3 using AWS console in one region and I was not aware of region by upload in aws. Today I just changed in region in aws console url and found that content is same. If it reflects automatically then what is the point of specifying region when uploading to S3 or any other aws service.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your confusion it's not very clear how this work. However this is how it works IMO:

> You can choose a region to optimize latency, minimize costs, or address regulatory requirements. Objects stored in a region never leave that region unless you explicitly transfer them to another region. For more information about regions, see [Accessing a Bucket](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html#access-bucket-intro) in the Amazon Simple Storage Service Developer Guide.

Therefore when you create a bucket you are being asked to choose the regions thus your bucket has got regions specific address i.e.:

`s3-<region>.amazonaws.com`

If you are able to see the same content of the bucket in different regions then most likely you have enabled cross-region replication.

> Cross-region replication is the automatic, asynchronous copying of
>   objects across buckets in different AWS regions. By activating
>   cross-region replication, Amazon S3 will replicate newly created
>   objects, object updates, and object deletions from a source bucket
>   into a destination bucket in a different region. Cross-region
>   replication has specific requirements that define what can and cannot
>   be replicated across regions based on how the object is created and
>   how it is encrypted. For more information, see [Cross-Region
>   Replication](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/crr.html) the Amazon Simple Storage Service Developer Guide.

You have asked:

> If it reflects automatically then what is the point of specifying region when uploading to S3 or any other aws service.

As per above it doesn't reflect automatically and the main points are:

- optimize latency -- the closer the servers are to you or your clients the lower the latency
- minimize costs -- you can avoid extra charges for data transfers, some regions are cheaper then others, etc.
- address regulatory requirements -- you or your clients may need to meet regulatory requirements i.e. data can't leave the USA or Europe or something similar